# PHP multidimensional arrays with foreach troubles

Tags: php, arrays, foreach

I have a little problem , I hope you can help me. I want to create a table with some details, about name,surname, age etc...

One array is made by:

```
array:2 [▼
  0 => array:9 [▼
    "ID" => 424
    "name" => "Alex"
    "surname" => "Pippo"
    "age" => 23

  ]
  1 => array:9 [▼
    "ID" => 424
    "name" => "Pippo"
    "surname" => "James"
    "age" => "21"

  ]
```

and I have another multidimensional array as follow:

```
  0 => array:2 [▼
    0 => array:3 [▼
      "class" => "VA"
      "sport" => "football"
      "height" => "1.55"
    ]
    1 => array:3 [▼
      "class" => "VA"
      "sport" => "basketball"
      "height" => "1.55"
    ]
  ]
  1 => array:1 [▼
    0 => array:3 [▼
      "class" => "VB"
      "sport" => "none"
      "height" => "1,76"
    ]
  ]
]
```

I want to have have a table in which i have details about students and their sports. So in the view i got:

```php
        <table border="1" cellspacing="5">
    <th >ID</th>
    <th >Name</th>
    <th >surName</th>
    <th >age</th>

            @foreach($data  as $datas)

            <tr>
            <td><?php echo($datas['id']) ?></td>
            <td><?php echo($datas['name']) ?></td>
            <td><?php echo($datas['surname']) ?></td>
            <td><?php echo($datas['age']) ?></td>
                <table>
                    <th>class</th>
                    <th>sport</th>
                    <th>age</th>
                            <tr>
                                @foreach($data1  as $datas1)
                                    @foreach($datas1 as $key => $value)
                                <td ><?php echo($value['class']) ?></td>
                                <td ><?php echo($value['sport']) ?> </td>
                                <td ><?php echo($value['height']) ?> </td>
                             </tr>
                </table>
                @endforeach
                @endforeach
                @endforeach
            </tr>
</table>
```

I want to have two tables, one inside the other one.

```
ID  Name    surName     Age
424     Alex    Pippo       23

Class   Sport      Height
VA      Football   1,55
VA      basketball 1,55
VB      none       1,76      *THIS BELONGS TO THE SECOND STUDENT

ID  Name    surName     Age
425     Pippo   James       22
Class   Sport      Height
VA      Football   1,55      *THIS BELONGS TO THE FIRST STUDENT
VA      basketball 1,55      *THIS BELONGS TO THE FIRST STUDENT
VB      none       1,76
```

i just want for the first one the first 2 rows, and for the second one the third row.. Please help..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on your data, it seems that the key of `$data1` is the same as the key to your student (`$data`). So, you need to connect both of them to get their relevant data.

The first step, you need to get the key to your student:

```
@foreach($data as $keys => $datas)
```

and only loop this student detail:

```
@foreach($data1[$keys] as $key => $value)
  <tr>
    <td ><?php echo($value['class']) ?></td>
    <td ><?php echo($value['sport']) ?></td>
    <td ><?php echo($value['height']) ?></td>
  </tr>
@endforeach
```

Comment: That actually solved my problem! I thought i wasn't clear, but you understood me. So happy thank you!